# Can't boot after upgrading to Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, kubuntu, bluetooth

I had a perfectly working Kubuntu installation. When I upgraded to 23.04, the upgrade was done without any error, but after a restart I wasn't able to load Kubuntu 23.04. My boot is stuck here:

[image: a photo of a black screen with white text]

I can use tty with ALT+CTRL+F2. After I login, I updated everything but it doesn't help. It looks like I've some kind of bluetooth error? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: is xorg and sddm installed?

Comment: Both of them are installed. I used following commands to check them: “cat etc/X11/default-display-manager” and “dpkg -l | grep xorg”. So what next?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally l solved the issue. Here are 2 simple steps to do:

1. Login to tty via ALT+CTRL+F2
2. sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

That’s all. Good luck ☺️